# Generation letters and numbers to create tracking Code

Tags: php

I need Generate a tracking code with php like `a00000001` up to `a99999999` One by one to be produced and if `a` Came to `a99999999` , `b‍` letter be start such as the `a` letter 
First letter of tracking code Start from `a` to `z` and other `8` nmber start from `00000001` to `99999999`

Comment: You need some form of persistent storage. Easiest is a database, a simple file can also be used but is more expensive from a performance point of view. Store all individual components of the final number (so the letter and the number here). When generating a _new_ code simply increment the number previously stored. If it reaches the `99999999`, then increment the letter and reset the number to `00000000`. As easy as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<?php
    $alpha='a';
    $num=1;
   /* put this in a function */
    $num=str_pad($num, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if($num==99999999){
      $alpha++;
      $num=1;
    }
   /* function ends here */
    $alpha .=$num;
echo $alpha."<br />";

   /* call that function while incrementing so as to check the number has not reached 99999999 */
    $alpha++; //this increment must happen in the function
echo $alpha."<br />";

?>
```

Output :

```
a00000001
a00000002
```

Increment `$alpha` as you want, once it reaches `a99999999` it will become `b00000001`

Comment: can you more explain how can i increment `$nume` to create what i want

Comment: Just do a `num++` in you code where ever required, the rest of it will be handled by the if statement(as shown above).

Comment: I use `$num++` in my code , but still the value is `a00000001`

Comment: @amirali do `$alpha++` as shown above. And make a function which you can call for the increment.(as put in comments)

Comment: @AniMenon You have a problem that appears after `a99999999` (`b1` instead of `b00000001`. Try using str_pad as late as possible: `echo $alpha . str_pad($num, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`.

Comment: @SteeveDroz If you read the comments(in code above)  you can see I have asked the OP to create a function which will do that. Then he may call it to increment.